# Swift: Decode NSString from php

Tags: json, swift, xcode, nested

I have the following code that I cannot get responseString split / decoded into parts.  I am looking to be able to get this into variables that I can use throughout the program. (First post ever, thank you for your patience).  I cannot get responseString to work outside of the {} brackets and I cannot JSON decode within the brackets.

```
    @IBAction func onLogin(_ sender: Any) {

        let loginUserSend = loginUser.text
        let loginPasswordSend = loginPassword.text

    if loginUserSend!.isEmpty {

        loginError.text = "Please input user name"
        loginError.textColor = UIColor.red

    } else if loginPasswordSend!.isEmpty {

        loginError.text = "Please input password"
        loginError.textColor = UIColor.red

} else {

print ("Moving to php request:")

let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "http://www.website.com/IOS/connectionIOSlogin.php")! as URL)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
print("Request: \(request)")

let postString = "loginUser=\(loginUser.text!) "
request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
print("postString: \(postString)")

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
(data, response, error) in

if error != nil {
    print("error=\(error)")
    return

} // Ends errror If statements
    
    //print("response = \(response)")
    let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
    print("responseString = \(responseString)")
    
}


task.resume()
```

Which returns the following:

```
Moving to php request:
Request: <NSMutableURLRequest: 0x600002bdc180> { URL: http://www.website.com/IOS/connectionIOSlogin.php }
postString: loginUser=Test1
 
2020-09-22 20:34:55.471811-0300 ABCDEF GHIJK[17260:1385975] [] nw_protocol_get_quic_image_block_invoke dlopen libquic failed

responseString = Optional(Row :Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [C_Id] => 1
    [1] => Test1
    [C_User] => Test1
    [2] => Test1
    [C_Pword] => Test1
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [C_Id] => 1
    [1] => Test1
    [C_User] => Test1
    [2] => Test1
    [C_Pword] => Test1
)
)
```